# Check whether checkbox in a jquery datatable row is checked or not

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am new to JQuery and datatables. I have a datatable with three columns in a row. First column is a checkbox and other two columns are text. I want to check whether the first column(checkbox) is checked or not on some event. I am able to get the other fields but i don't know how to check if the checkbox is checked. I have the row id and i am using the below code to get the row and the other columns

```
function uncheckRow(trId) {<br>
    var table = $(‘#example’).DataTable();
    var row = table.row("#"+trId);
    var rowData = row.data();
    var name = rowData[1];
    var age = rowData[2];
    // need to check if the check box in the 1st column(rowData[0]) is checked or not, If it is checked, i have to uncheck
    …
}
```

I also tried the below approach, it is working fine. But when i move to next page using pagination, this is not working.

```
var td = $("#"+trId).find("td");
var chkBox = td.eq(0).find('input');
if(chkBox.is(':checked')){
    chkBox.prop('checked', false);
}
```

Please provide the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: can you add html sample ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can access the node in memory if you have a reference to the row object, regardless if it's in the DOM or not.

```
function uncheckRow(trId) {
    var table = $(‘#example’).DataTable();
    var row = table.row("#"+trId);
    var rowData = row.data();
    var name = rowData[1];
    var age = rowData[2];

    var $tr = $(row.node());
    var $checkbox = $tr.find('td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]')
    if($checkbox.is(':checked')){
        $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. For some reason $checkbox.is(':checked') always return 'false' even though the check box is checked.

Comment: I would look at $checkbox in the browser dev tools and see if it's actually a checkbox.

Comment: Hi Eric, this code is working as expected. var row = table.row("#"+trId).node();
 var chkBox = $(row.cells[0]).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
 if(chkBox.is(':checked')){
  chkBox.prop('checked', false);
 }

Answer (score 0):

This may work. Link attached below has full demo with jquery datatable.

DataTable with Checkbox demo: https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/

Comment: While this link may provide an answer, it is better to summarize the main points in your post, as links can become non-operational.

Comment: Sure @adrian-mole, Will summarise the answer with main point. Thanks for the good suggestion. :)